# How to use router properly in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I want to make my website multilingual, however when I write the code it is:

```
 <a class="language-English row" href="recruit/en">
```

it will give a path as: http://localhost:8080/recruit/recruit/en
what if the code is:

```
<a class="language-English row" href="/en">
```

It takes me back to the home page again.... So what do I need to deal with here? Do I need further processing in the router.js file?  Hope to get help ^^

Update:
So if I handle the router like this:

```
    path: '/recruit',
    name: 'Recruit',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Recruit" */ '../views/Recruit/index.vue'),
    children: [
      {
          path: "/recruit/:locale",
          component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Recruit" */ '../views/Recruit/index.vue'),
      },
  ],
  },
```

was it correct? and in a href tag how do i put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, there is no need for nested routing here:

```js
{
    path: '/recruit/:locale',
    name: 'Recruit',
    component: () => import('../views/Recruit/index.vue') // chunk name is set automatically.
},
```

Now in the template

```html
 <a class="language-English row" href="/recruit/en">English</a>
                                       ^
```

Don't miss the leading slash. If there is no leading slash, the router just joins the path to the current URL in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use nested routes here.

Since your link is like this,

```
/recruit/recruit/en
```

In your routes.js file you can add,

```
    {
        path: "/recruit",
        component: YourComponentHere,
        children: [
            {
                path: "/recruit/:lang",
                component: YourComponentHere,
            },
        ],
    },
```

And you can access `:lang` in your `child component` by using,

```
<template>
 <h1>Language is {{ $route.params.lang }} </h1>
</template>
```

Or if you are using `<script setup>`,

```
<script setup>
import {useRoute} from 'vue-router';

const Router = useRoute();
</script>

<template>
 <h1>Language is {{ Router.params.lang }} </h1>
</template>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have updated the question, hope you can explain more, thank you very much

Comment: You can use <router-link :to=""></router-link> You don't need to use <a href>. If the route is dynamic use :to="" else use just to=""

Comment: So how should I put the syntax inside <router-link: to = ""> </router-link>? Thanks

Comment: <router-link to="/recruit/recruit/en">Language English</router-link>